# Асинхронное изменение переменной на node.js и socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Есть код на сервере:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var formidable = require('formidable');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = 3000;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');


var unitSize = mongoose.model('size', { param: Number });
var unitSpeed = mongoose.model('speed', { param: Number });
var size = new unitSize({ param: 22 });
var speed = new unitSpeed({ param: 4 });

io.on("connection", function(socket) {  
  console.log("an user connected " + socket.id);
  var controlPanelParametrs = {
     size : size.param,
     speed: speed.param
  }
  io.sockets.emit('control_panel_param', controlPanelParametrs);
)};
```

И есть код на клиенте:

```
 var socket = socket = io.connect(window.location.host);
 var unitSize;
 var unitSpeed;

 socket.on('control_panel_param', function(data){
    unitSize = data.size;
    unitSpeed = data.speed;

    console.log(unitSize, unitSpeed);
 });
 console.log(unitSize, unitSpeed);
```

В консоли выводит вначале undefined, undefined.
А потом 22 и 4.

Если из консоли вызвать console.log(unitSize), то выведет вначале число, а после undefined.

Как сделать, чтобы выводило только число и не было никаких undefined?

Comment: *Уберите тот вызов console.log, который выводит undefined. Тогда undefined выводиться не будет.*

Comment: Это же не решение. Мне нужно позже использовать unitSize и unitSpeed в коде, а как же их использовать, если они не определены

Comment: А вы используйте их когда они станут определены.

Comment: я уже когда страница полностью загрузилась в инструментах разработчика ввожу console.log(unitSpeed); и выводится undefined.

Comment: Значит, страница еще не успела их получить

Comment: но они же вывелись в консоли, вначале, ещё когда страница грузилась. А потом когда я их запрашиваю - пусто.

Comment: Значит, вы что-то напутали.

Answer (score -1):

Как сделать, чтобы выводило только число и не было никаких undefined?

```
 var socket = io.connect(window.location.host);
 socket.on('control_panel_param', data => {        
     console.log(data.size, data.speed); // Числа
 });
```

Comment: Так а проблема в том, что вне функции listener, даже после её выполнения console.log(unitSize, unitSpeed); все равно выведет undefined.

Comment: Ваш console.log выполняется *до*  того как выполняется listener

Comment: Так и после того как функция выполнилась, значение глобальной переменной остается прежним.

Comment: @DmitriyRudenko Я обновил ответ. Как вы проверяете, что функция уже выполнилась?

Comment: после того как страница загрузилась в инструментах разработчика пишу console.log(unitSize); Вначале выводит число, а потом undefined. Мне же нужно, чтобы значение глобальной переменной изменилось, а не только в пределах функции control_panel_param